# How to convert column entries to binary (0 or 1) from dates?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In the date_died column of the dataset, I want to convert the column into a column with the heading 'Survived' where: if date_died is 9999-99-99 then survived = 1 else survived = 0 [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yYUU.png)]. I want to use that column as my output data frame. I am an absolute beginner at ML and python.

Comment: what to do if date_died is empty ?

Comment: This is a `pandas` question and not a `machine-learning` one, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use np.where for this,

```
df['Survived'] = np.where(df['date_died'].eq("9999-99-99"), 1, 0)
```

See a dummy example below,

```
df['date_died'] = ['9999-99-99', '9999-99-99', '2020-02-14', '2020-03-10', np.nan]

df['Survived'] = np.where(df['date_died'].eq("9999-99-99"), 1, 0)

df

    date_died   Survived
0   9999-99-99  1
1   9999-99-99  1
2   2020-02-14  0
3   2020-03-10  0
4   NaN         0
```

If you want to make Survived as 1 when date_died is np.nan, then you can change the code slightly as shown below,

```
df['Survived'] = np.where((df['date_died'].eq("9999-99-99")) | (df['date_died'].isna()), 1, 0)
```